# Transversal duality for upwards-closed subsets of ${\cal P}(X)$

Tags: combinatorics, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let $X$ be a set. Recall that an $U\subseteq {\cal P}(X)$ is **upwards-closed** if $A\in U, A\subseteq B \Rightarrow B\in U$ for any $A,B \subseteq X$. I'll write "ucs" as a shorthand for upwards-closed set.

Clearly, an ucs on $X$ contains $\emptyset$ iff it coincides with the whole of ${\cal P}(X)$ ; in this case, or if it is empty, I call it degenerate.

For any $Y \subseteq {\cal P}(X)$, define 
$${\cal T}(Y)=\lbrace Z \subseteq X \ | \ \forall y\in Y, Z \cap y \neq \emptyset\rbrace \tag{1}$$

(the so-called "transversals" on $Y$). This is clearly an ucs on $X$, and it is nondegenerate as soon as $\emptyset\not\in Y$ and $Y\neq \emptyset$.

**My question :** Can one show in ZFC that ${\cal T}({\cal T}(U))=U$ for any nondegenerate ucs $U$ (or find a counterexample) ? Can one show it in ZF ?

**My thoughts :** There is a dual construction to (1) : for $F\subseteq {\cal P}(X)$, let 
$${\cal U}_X(F)=\lbrace Z \subseteq X \ | \ \exists f\in F, f \subseteq Z\rbrace\tag{2}$$
This is clearly an ucs on $X$.

I say that $U$ is "finitely generated" when it is of the form ${\cal U}_X(F)$ for a finite $F\subseteq {\cal P}(X)$. In that case, the study of ${\cal T}(U)$ reduces to the computation of transversals over a finite set. Indeed,  write $F=\lbrace F_1,F_2,\ldots,F_r \rbrace$ where $F_i \subseteq X$. Then there are disjoint subsets $G_1,G_2,\ldots,G_s$ (with $s\leq 2^r$) of $X$ such that each $F_i$ is a finite union of $G_j$'s', say $F_i=\bigcup_{j\in H_i} G_j$ where $H_i \subseteq \lbrace 1,2,\ldots, s \rbrace$. Let $X'=\lbrace 1,2,\ldots, s \rbrace$ and let $I'$ be the ideal on $X'$ defined by $U'={\cal U}_{X'}(\lbrace H_1,H_2,\ldots,H_r\rbrace)$. Then, it is easy to check that

$$
{\cal T}(U)={\cal U}(L)
$$

where

$$
L=\bigg\lbrace \bigcup_{j\in U} G_j \bigg| U \in I'  \bigg\rbrace
$$

So if the result is true when $X$ is finite, it will automatically
follow for finitely generated upward-closed sets.

**Update 09/08/2019 :** A concrete example : if $X=\lbrace 1,2,3,4,5,6 \rbrace $ and 
$$ U={\cal U}_X(\lbrace \lbrace 1,2,3 \rbrace, \lbrace 3,4,5 \rbrace, \lbrace 1,5,6 \rbrace  \rbrace)$$

then

$$ {\cal T}(U)={\cal U}_X(\lbrace \lbrace 1,3 \rbrace, \lbrace 1,4 \rbrace, \lbrace 1,5 \rbrace, \lbrace 2,5 \rbrace, \lbrace 3,5 \rbrace, \lbrace 3,6 \rbrace, \lbrace 2,4,6 \rbrace  \rbrace)$$

In any similar example where $X$ is finite, the identity ${\cal T}({\cal T}(U))=U$ is readily verified, but I was unable to construct a general proof.

Comment: If $U$ is a filter, then yes.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Why ? When $X$ is finite every filter $F$ is generated by a single subset, $F={\cal U}(Z)$ for some subset $Z$ of $X$, and then ${\cal T}(F)={\cal U}(\lbrace z \rbrace_{z\in Z})$, but what about the infinite case ?

Comment: If $U$ is a filter, then a set that meets every set that meets every set that is in $U$, is already in $U$. Otherwise, its complement must also meet every set in $U$, and then it doesn't meet every set that meets every set that is in $U$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy would you be happy with a proof for finite $X$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila In fact, you don't need $U$ to be a filter, you just need $U$ to be upwards-closed, this is the argument in Alex Ravsky's answer.

Comment: Ewan, my argument wasn't about finite sets, of course. It seems plausible that you can get this for every ucs, yes. What would be interesting, though, is to note that $U\subseteq\mathcal{TT}(U)$. So are the fixed points exactly the ucs (or at least filters)?

Comment: @AsafKaragila It seems you misunderstood me : I never said or thought your argument was only about finite sets. What I thought and said was, that you don't need the extra assumption that $U$ is a filter for your argument to work. The finite-intersection property (which distinguishes filters from mere ucses) is not used in your argument.

Comment: @Ewan: I see. That's a good point. Feel free to post that as an answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It has already  been posted as an answer by Alex Ravsky, see below :-)

Comment: I'm confused. His answer talks about finite sets...

Comment: @AsafKaragila You needn't be confused : notice how his second paragraph ends with : "its proof also can be simplified to obtain a positive answer for the case of (not necessarily finite) sets as follows"

Comment: @EwanDelanoy But he does start off with "Let $U$ ... of a finite sets $X$".

Comment: @AsafKaragila The proof given at the end doesn't use anything about $X$ being finite.

Comment: Then why is it in the assumptions of the statement? You can figure this out with Alex. I have a busy week ahead.

Comment: @mathworker21 The set $X$ in the second paragraph of my answer is not necessarily finite, the statement about its finiteness was a misprint. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The fixed points (non-empty $U$ such that $U\subset {\cal T}({\cal T}(U))$) are exactly ucs, because this equality holds for ucs and ${\cal T}(V)$ is an ucs for any family $V\subset\mathcal P(X)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Surely this has been already studied somewhere, under another name perhaps

Yes, I even was an opponent of a PhD thesis"[Algebraic and topological structures on the superextensions](http://gavrylkiv.pu.if.ua/papers/autoreferat.pdf)" by Volodymyr Gavrylkiv (English abstract starts at p. 17). Proposition 3.6.1 of the thesis is stated for topological spaces and directly implies the positive answer for a finite set $X$, considered as a topological space endowed with a discrete topology. But its proof also can be simplified to obtain a positive answer for the case of (not necessarily finite) sets as follows.

Let $U$ be a non-degenerate ucs of subsets of a set $X$. Clearly, $U\subset {\cal T}({\cal T}(U))$. On the other hand, assume that there exists a set $F\in {\cal T}({\cal T}(U))\setminus U$. Since $F\not\in U$, $X\setminus F\in {\cal T}(U)$. But $F\in {\cal T}({\cal T}(U))$, so $F\cap (X\setminus F)\ne\varnothing$, a contradiction.

Comment: Nice and simple, +1 (and you'll probably get the bounty too, though as a question of principle I always wait before attributing the bounty). What do you mean by "I was an <<opponent>> of a PhD thesis" ? Do you mean you disagreed with its content ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy I'm unfamiliar with policies about bounties. Isn't the norm to award to whomever is the first to provide a correct answer?

Comment: @mathworker21 my policy is to award the bounty to the best answer (or the first to post it if there are equivalent answers). All the same, I think you'll find it hard to improve on this answer.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy okay, to each his/her own I guess, but I think if someone works really hard on a difficult question to come up with a solution, and then someone else reads that solution and cleans it up a fair amount, then the first person should get the bounty (not to diminish the contribution of the cleaner-upper though).

Comment: @EwanDelanoy In my country (and, I guess in many post-USSR countries), "opponent" is a name for an official reviewer for a Ph.D. or habilitation thesis. I think its opinion is one most important for a decision whether the thesis should be accepted. But he is not a devil's advocate (usually an opponent supports the thesis), but only a specialist who have studied the thesis and proposes his review and remarks to it to a scientific council, which then decides, whether the author of the thesis should be awarded by a degree or not.

Comment: @mathworker21 If anybody has an answer which worths a bounty I don't mind him for posting it. I'm not greedy for my reputation (if I could, I'd remove it at all). [I'm looking for bounty questions as for good unanswered questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2387879/weak-composition-with-restrictions0-9#comment4937263_2393221). Also the idea of the proof for the present answer is not mine, I adapted that from the thesis.