# How to show relation between squarefree sets

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Edit: I erase the last question and post specific problems

Consider
$$\text{If $t$ is prime, then set}\quad \mathcal{A}(t)=\left\{ N; \quad N=\prod_{\substack{p_i \text{ is prime}\\ 2t\ \nmid\ p_i-1}}p_i ,\text{ and $N$ is squarfree}\right\}\cup \{1\}$$
$$\text{If $t$ is composite, say $t=q_1\times q_2\times\ldots\times q_s$  for some $s$ then set}
    \quad\mathcal{A}(t)=\mathcal{A}(q_1)\cap\mathcal{A}(q_2)\cap\ldots\cap\mathcal{A}(q_s)$$ Where $q_i$ are distinct prime factor of $t$.

Consider set $\mathcal{B}(l)=\{ t: l\in\mathcal{A}(t)\}$ then **show that**,

$$\text{If $l$ is prime, then set}\quad \mathcal{B}(l)=\left\{ N; \quad N=\prod_{\substack{p_i \text{ is prime}\\ p_i\ \nmid\ l-1}}p_i \right\}$$
$$\text{If $l$ is composite and squarefree, say $l=q^`_1\times q^`_2\times\ldots\times q^`_{s^`}$  for some $s^`$ then set}
    \quad\mathcal{B}(l)=\mathcal{B}(q^`_1)\cap\mathcal{B}(q^`_2)\cap\ldots\cap\mathcal{B}(q^`_{s^`})$$ where $q^`_i$ are distinct prime factors of $l$.

Table for lists,

| $\mathcal{A}(t)$ | sets |
| --- | --- |
| $\mathcal{A}(1)$ | $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, \ldots\}$ |
| $\mathcal{A}(2)$ | $\{1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 11, 14, 19, 22, 23, 31, 38, 43, 46, 47, 59, 62, 67, 71, 79, \ldots\}$ |
| $\mathcal{A}(3)$ | $\{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 11, 15, 17, 22, 23, 29, 30, 33, 34, 41, 46, 47, 51, 53, \ldots\}$ |
| $\mathcal{A}(4)$ | $\{1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 11, 14, 19, 22, 23, 31, 38, 43, 46, 47, 59, 62, 67, 71, 79, \ldots\}$ |
| $\mathcal{A}(5)$ | $\{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 26, 29, 30, 34, 35, 37, \ldots\}$ |
| $\mathcal{A}(6)$ | $\{1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 22, 23, 46, 47, 59, 71, 83, 94, 107, 118, 131, 142, 166, 167, 179, \ldots\}$ |
| $\mathcal{A}(7)$ | $\{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 26, 30, 31, 33, \ldots\}$ |
| $\mathcal{A}(8)$ | $\{1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 11, 14, 19, 22, 23, 31, 38, 43, 46, 47, 59, 62, 67, 71, 79, \ldots\}$ |
| $\mathcal{A}(9)$ | $\{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 11, 15, 17, 22, 23, 29, 30, 33, 34, 41, 46, 47, 51, 53, \ldots\}$ |
| $\mathcal{A}(10)$ | $\{1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 19, 23, 38, 43, 46, 47, 59, 67, 79, 83, 86, 94, 103, 107, \ldots\}$ |
| $\vdots$ | $\vdots$ |

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
& \text{Set} \\
\hline
\mathcal{B}(2) & \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, \ldots, 99, 100\} \\
\mathcal{B}(3) & \{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, \ldots, 97, 99\} \\
\mathcal{B}(4) & \{1\} \\
\mathcal{B}(5)& \{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, \ldots, 97, 99\} \\
\mathcal{B}(6) & \{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, \ldots, 97, 99\} \\
\mathcal{B}(7)& \{1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, \ldots, 89, 91, 95, 97\} \\
\mathcal{B}(8) & \{1\} \\
\mathcal{B}(9) & \{1\} \\
\mathcal{B}(10) & \{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, \ldots, 97, 99\} \\
\mathcal{B}(11) & \{1, 3, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, 19, 21, \ldots, 93, 97, 99\} \\
\mathcal{B}(12) & \{1\} \\
\mathcal{B}(13)& \{1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, \ldots, 95, 97\} \\
\mathcal{B}(14)& \{1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, \ldots, 95, 97\} \\
\mathcal{B}(15)& \{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, \ldots, 97, 99\} \\
\mathcal{B}(16) & \{1\} \\
\mathcal{B}( 17) & \{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, \ldots, 97, 99\} \\
\hline
\end{array}

Comment: What do $A_{ij}$ and $B_{kl}$ mean?  Also, your quantifiers are unclear.  Is the double implication meant to hold *for all* $4-$tuples $(i,j,k,l)$?  *At least one*?  Something else?  For example, are $k,l$ meant to be functions of $i,j$?

Comment: @lulu $ij$ means $i$ times $j$. for example $A_2=\{2n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $A_3=\{3n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ then $A_2\cap A_3=A_6=\{6n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Comment: I still don't understand what quantifiers you had in mind.  Perhaps it would help if you edited your post to include an explicit, non-trivial example of the phenomenon you are interested in.

Comment: @Pruthviraj, what did you try in order to solve your exercise ? Read [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is being closed by moderators because it is a very low-quality question.

Comment: I don't understand your example, and I don't understand why you don't answer my question about quantifiers.  Letting $A_i$ denote the multiples of $i$ does not follow your condition, or at least it doesn't appear to.  With that choice, $A_i\cap A_j=A_{\text {lcm} (i,j)}$.  Thus $A_2\cap A_6=A_6$, not $A_{12}$ (which should not be confused with $A_{1\times 2}$).

Comment: @lulu yes there should be lcm use because  this problem is came from my previous problem where i posted it on mathoverflow https://mathoverflow.net/q/461431/149083 but i didn't describe how it is exactly related. I will do that soon

Comment: As it stands, the question makes no apparent sense.  I suggest deleting it and reposting when you have sorted out the details.

Comment: @lulu is it understandable now

Comment: In any case:  like the prior version of the question, this one should be edited.  Whatever you meant to ask, presumably you can check special cases.  If $q_1,q_2$ are two odd primes, then you could analyze $t=q_1\times q_2$, for instance.  Working a special case explicitly (don't omit the details) might clarify things.

Comment: As a particular point that requires clarification:  In your definition of $A(t)$ for composite $t$, are you assuming that $t$ is square free?  Similarly in your proposed description of $B(l)$.

Comment: I disagree with your table for $\mathcal A(t)$. First, each element from $\mathcal A(t)$ is a product of
primes, so $1\not\in \mathcal A(t)$. Second, already for $t=2$ the set $P_2$ of primes $p$ such that
$2t\ \nmid\ p-1$ is rather big. Namely, it consists of $2$ and all primes of the form $4n+1$.
Thus the set $\mathcal A(2)$ is not $\{1,2\}$  but consists of all products of distinct elements of $P_2$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky i apologies to not correct it yet, now please recheck it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us show what is required in the question.

For each natural $n$ put $[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

Suppose that $l$ is prime. Let $t$ be a product of distinct prime numbers $t_1,\dots, t_k$. Then $t\in \mathcal B(l)$ iff $l\in\mathcal A(t)$ iff $l\in\mathcal A(t_j)$ for any $j\in [k]$ iff $l=\prod_{\substack{p_i \text{ is prime}\\ 2t_j\ \nmid\ p_i-1}}p_i$ for any $j\in [k]$ iff
$2t_j\ \nmid\ l-1$ for any $j\in [k]$. We have to compare the latter condition with $t_j\ \nmid\ l-1$ for any $j\in [k]$. Their equivalence can be easily checked for $l>2$ and for $l=2$ separately.

Suppose now that $l$ is a product of distinct prime numbers $p_1,\dots, p_n$. Let $t$ be a product of distinct prime numbers $t_1,\dots, t_k$. Then $t\in \mathcal B(l)$ iff $l\in\mathcal A(t)$ iff
$l\in\mathcal A(t_j)$ for any $j\in [k]$ iff $2t_j\ \nmid\ p_i-1$ for any $i\in [n]$ and $j\in [k]$ iff
$t\in\mathcal B(p_i)$ for any $i\in [n]$.

Comment: thank you for your answer , Im on understanding this, I have just posted related Questions on mathoverflow [https://mathoverflow.net/q/462029/149083]

Comment: I'm really sorry, i just forgot to give you bounty.

Comment: @Pruthviraj Never mind, [I am not a bounty hunter](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2387879/weak-composition-with-restrictions0-9#comment4937263_2393221).

Answer (score 2):

Seems false.

Pick $A_1 = \mathbb{N} / \{1\}$ and for $n>1, A_n = \varnothing$.

Check that $A_i \cap A_j = A_{ij} $ $\forall i,j \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now $B_1 = \varnothing $ since $1\notin A_i $ $\forall i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $B_2 = \{1\}$ since $2 \in A_1$.
By the assumption we have:

$B_2 = B_1 \cap B_2 = \varnothing \cap \{1\} = \varnothing$. A contradiction.

Comment: I'm sorry but i have change the direction of the last question can you please go with this because last problem is very unclear and have to specify it.